# Where is APK file stored after phonegap android build is successful?

Tags: android, cordova

I don't understand where can I find my package that is compiled so I can copy it into my device and install it from there.

What I did is create an empty project, then made build on it with no errors, however, I cannot find `.apk` file.

`\platforms\android\bin` has `HelloWorld-debug.apk` but I don't want to debug package but a normal one.

I tried `phonegap build android` as well as `phonegap build android local` and no difference was found between these two commands. Also, why is it even named `HelloWorld` if I named my project `lololol`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using eclipse? If so, take a look at this tutorial. This will allow you to export to a .apk file.

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/build-android-application-package-file-apk-using-eclipse-ide/

Comment: No, I'm using command line. Is there any way to generate `.apk` files using command line?

Comment: I've never done it before but it looks like these will tell you how to do it.  
 
Here's a guide to releasing from the command line: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html#ReleaseMode  
 
Here's a better guide to signing the .apk file, if you need to do that as well: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Yea, now I have `HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk`. I still don't get it why it's called HelloWorld tho.. ))

Answer (score 20):

You can change the name of the app after to create the project, in the file:

> ProjectFolder/www/config.xml

After that, you have to build again the project. If you want the release version, go to

> ProjectFolder/platforms/android/cordova

and then execute the command:

> cordova build --release

This creates an unsigned release APK at ProjectFolder/platforms/android/bin folder, called YourAppName-release-unsigned.apk.

Comment: I have done this, and I do not have a "bin" folder in that folder path.

Comment: Wich version of Phonegap/Cordova are you using? This is only for version 3.3. In the new version (3.4) your folder is called ant-bin, but it's the same

Comment: I have "ant-build" is this the proper .apk file?  The reason I'm asking is because the the "AppName" is different that what I've specified in the config.xml even after I've done a build again.

Comment: Yes, the .apk file is this folder, you can check it executing the app. I don't know why your app doesn't have the proper name… :S

Comment: Are your sure is not at phonegap_project_folder/config.xml?

Answer (score 9):

Phonegap 5.4.0 puts them in platforms/android/build/outputs/apk

I ran `phonegap build --release` to do this. Still trying to figure all this out however!

Comment: Where the .apk file located?

Comment: This is the answer

Answer (score 3):

Check out platforms/android/build.xml for where "HelloWorld" comes from, maybe.  In my case, I have a line that says

```
<project name="CordovaApp" default="help">
```

and my app gets named "CordovaApp-release.apk", instead of what I have in config.xml.  I assume the "cordova platform add android" is doing something slightly wrong, but not entirely sure.

Answer (score 2):

in the newest versions the apk file should be located at /platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/

Comment: I don't see a build folder under android/app

Comment: @Hemant.Gupta make sure to run phonegap build android --release  first as mentioned in the previous answers

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this only applies to cordova-android@^7.0.0 (I use 7.1.4 and the generated APK is there)

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing they moved the location of the apk again.
Here is my version and the new location:

> >phonegap -v
>
> 8.0.0

location of apk after

> >phonegap build android --release

**[project_folder]\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release**

Note the extra \app folder.