# What and where is the app when I'm using cordova?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, web-applications

I apolagize in advance for the extreme noobiness of my question...

I'm on mac os and using cordova to build an app. I know nothing of java or c, so the only thing I did was to put my index, js and css files in the www folder and test it with the CLI.

```
$ cordova emulate /* with android and ios */
$ cordova run     /* with android and ios */
$ cordova build
```

I was able to make the app work on android and ios virtual and real devices, and got the BUILD SUCCEEDED message on my terminal.

But to be honest none of this is familiar and if it wasn't for a tutorial I read one line at a time I wouldn't have been able to do it.

The probleme is the tutorial stops at the build step, and I can't find any other tutorial that explains very plainly and simply(not to say idiotically) how to go from there.
I'm left with lots of folder and have no idea what exactly is the app amongst all those files.

How can I put it on my website for download? Do I need an executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS and android you would typically have two different types of files.

iOS uses .ipa files and android uses .apk files.

I am not sure about Cordova, but generally the cross platform software would generate those two types of files, these can then be put onto the device and run.

Comment: But is it just those files or a directory containing those files? Have you hear of a good tutorial about this?

Comment: Possibly look at the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614437/where-is-apk-file-stored-after-phonegap-android-build-is-successful

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've found out more since 2014 but for others (like me landing here from google), in Windows, at the CMD command line, use

> WHERE CORDOVA

..to find where the cordova builder is actually located.

For Android, your output is an *.APK file which should be announced at the very end for the cordova console output, eg:

> C:/MyApps/TrialApp/phonegap/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk

..where C:\MyApps\TrialApp\phonegap\ is your phonegap project folder assuming you are using phonegap.

If you do not want to submit it to Google Play, you can host the *.apk on various hosts including your own site, a freebee like http://androidhost.org/ (care, may download trash to phones), http://slideme.org/ or https://www.voltcloud.io/ etc.

Hopefully that will give other newbies a heads up.